# Function of type bool receiving parameter (reference) and possibly return it in C++?

Tags: c++, function, reference

I have a homework task in my university where I should make a function of type `bool(double &var)` which takes a reference to the variable as a parameter. Then the function performs some calculations and should calculate the result in a new seperate variable, but at the same time return it in the `var` variable (the parameter of the function). I would like to ask how can this be accomplished? Below is a simple example of the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double rez;
bool func(double &var){
//var = 5;
if(var>3){
    rez = var;
    return var;
}
else{
    return false;
}
}
int main(){

}
```

Comment: You've misunderstood your instructions somewhere. Returning a `double` as a `bool` is impossible. Perhaps you're meant to _assign_ the calculation result to `var` and return `true` if there are no errors?

Comment: Why `rez = var;`? Actually, it should be the opposite, `var = /* the complicated calculation */; return true;` and `else return false;` without assignment of `var`. I don't get what role plays `rez`.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass-by-value. like `bool func(double var)`, what happens is that you get a local `var`, which will be gone if you leave scope. Imagine something like this:
A function

```
bool func(double var) {
     double res = var * 2;
     return true;
}
```

called like this:

```
double someVar = 5;
bool success = func(someVar);
```

You could calculate with `var` all you want, when returning from `func` the local copy `var` will be gone and you are left with `someVar == 5`.

Now, when you pass per reference (i.e. `bool func(double &var)`) everything you do with the passed `var` will be done to the original one. That means when returning from `func` you would be left with `someVar == 10`. `success` would be true in either way.

Hope this helps